# Hibernate - The column name att_id_1 is not valid

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

For some reason the query that is generated by hibernate is wrong. I have other tables/classes where the generated query is correct however for one table it is wrong. When I do a trace using MS Management Studio I see the following:

```
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,NULL,N'select aprresourc0_.agrtid as agrtid1_14_, aprresourc0_.att_id_1 as att_id_2_14_, 
aprresourc0_.att_id_2 as att_id_3_14_, aprresourc0_.att_id_3 as att_id_4_14_, aprresourc0_.att_id_4 as att_id_5_14_, 
aprresourc0_.attribute_id as attribut6_14_, aprresourc0_.bflag as bflag7_14_, aprresourc0_.client as client8_14_, ... 
from aprresourcepost aprresourc0_ 
where ...
select @p1
```

The columns att_id_1, att_id_2, att_id_3 and att_id_4 do not exist in the table or my Java class! 
How do I fix this? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to have been a simple mistake. I continued to work on the project and the next class I was looking at matched the query I was getting in my problem so I checked the code and found I was referencing the wrong class in my code!